# iOS7 slideout drawer draggable bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I am trying to implement a slideout drawer similar to a the one found in this guide: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

I have two subviews that are added to the navigation controller, The drawer is initialized as follows in viewDidLoad:

```
self.drawerViewController = [[DrawerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"drawer" bundle:nil];
self.drawerViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:self.drawerViewController.view];
[self addChildViewController: self.drawerViewController];
[self.drawerViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
self.drawerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

then the contentview is initialized using a viewcontroller from my storyboard (and i call send subviewtoback to move the drawer behind it):

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.contentViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.drawerViewController.view];
[self pushViewController:self.contentViewController animated:YES];
```

I move the main content view by animating the frame of the contentview which uncovers the drawer underneath:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:SLIDE_TIME delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{self.contentViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(150, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
                 }completion:nil];
```

Which works but if I do something like click the margin of the drawer and drag, the drawer can end up covering the entire screen in the iphone simulator or disappearing showing the black background (which is more easily reproduced when rotating the device while showing drawer). My question is why is the drawerview draggable and how do you prevent this?

Edit:
I have found the source of the dragging is from this addChildViewController line:

```
[self addChildViewController: self.drawerViewController];
```

However removing this doesnt allow users to click the table cells anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using a navigation controller as a container of subviews. I don't think it's meant to be used this way so I ended up scrapping this and rewriting it with a uiviewcontroller container instead.